# Identify server on Tomcat (HttpServletRequest.getLocalAddr() fails)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

With Tomcat setup behind Apache, how can an id (IP address ideally) of the server be easily determined?

The specific situation is that multiple servers are setup behind a load balancer, thus the incoming request host name is non-unique and insufficient to identify a particular server for logging purposes.  Using `HttpServletRequest.getLocalAddr()` is unfortunately returning the same hostname instead of the IP address as would be expected (I am assuming this is related to this very old issue here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46082).

Is there a way to make `getLocalAddr()` perform as documented, or are other methods required to query the IP address of the server?

Comment: do you want to return the address of the server receiving the request, or the address of the client sending a request to the server?

Comment: The server address is what I am looking for.  Trying to find an easy way to uniquely identify the server that received the request, without having to add per server configuration to accomodate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my situation, the solution was to get the IP address of the server directly instead of attempting to get the local address via HttpServleRequest.

I cached the IP for use in my filter via:

```
private static final String serverIp;
static {
    String addressString = null;
    try
    {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        addressString = address.getHostAddress();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception while attempting to determine local ip address",e);
    }

    if (addressString != null) serverIp = addressString;
    else serverIp = "unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On our project, we use JMX to get all the config information.
It takes a few steps, because it is like navigating down the server.xml file
This link has some info: http://oss.wxnet.org/mbeans.html

It is probably overkill if all you want is the IP, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

```
  MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
  Set<ObjectName> theConnectors = mbeanServer.queryNames(
      new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Connector,*"),
      null);
  if (theConnectors != null)
  {
      for (ObjectName nextConnectorName : theConnectors)
      {
        InetAddress theInetAddress = (InetAddress) mbeanServer.getAttribute(
          nextConnectorName,
          "address");
        if (theInetAddress != null)
        {
          ipAddress = theInetAddress.getHostAddress();
        }
        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
          // found the IP address
          break;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I am familiar with JMX, but without adding additional configuration parameters per server, I am not sure if there are any unique properties that would enable easy server identification.

Comment: Does your server.xml have the IP address that you're interested in? If so, there's probably a way to get it. 
I've added some code to my answer. It shows how you can find the Connector under your Engine. Your config is probably different, but you'll see the general approach.

Comment: +1, but I ended up taking a slightly more direct route (answered here as well) by just getting the IP address via `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently (a few years after the original question) and found this question and answers. The issue in my case was that the `ServletRequest#getLocalAddr()` implementation was returning the remote address instead of the local address. The issue was caused by a regression in Tomcat v9.0.22. It was fixed in v9.0.23. See the question and answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725039/9602527